# How to compile schema at build step?

Tags: build, schema, waf, gsettings

Waf 2.0.17 [glib2](https://waf.io/apidocs/tools/glib2.html) compiles and install the gsettings schemas
of [hamster](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster/commit/9565e5a8d545b77b6581557760b0415b371b28a2) smoothly.

Yet it is not possible to run the application without installing first:

```
python3 src/hamster-cli.py 

(hamster-cli.py:4690): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 17:27:08.176: 
Settings schema 'org.gnome.Hamster' is not installed
```

The workaround described in [First steps with GSettings](https://blog.gtk.org/2017/05/01/first-steps-with-gsettings/) does not work.

```
./waf configure build
```

> ...
>   [127/127] Compiling data/org.gnome.hamster.gschema.xml

```
GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=build/data python3 src/hamster-cli.py
```

> (hamster-cli.py:4850): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 17:31:56.381: Settings schema 'org.gnome.Hamster' is not installed
>       Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

```
GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=build/data gsettings describe org.gnome.hamster last-report-folder
```

> No such schema “org.gnome.hamster”

and indeed, there is only the empty `build/data/org.gnome.hamster.gschema.xml.valid` file that [serves as a target](https://waf.io/apidocs/tools/glib2.html#waflib.Tools.glib2.glib_validate_schema.hcode):

```
hcode = 'rm -f ${GLIB_VALIDATE_SCHEMA_OUTPUT} \
         && ${GLIB_COMPILE_SCHEMAS} --dry-run ${GLIB_COMPILE_SCHEMAS_OPTIONS} \
         && touch ${GLIB_VALIDATE_SCHEMA_OUTPUT}'
```

#### Workaround

Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/251713/821405):

```
glib-compile-schemas --targetdir=build/data data
```

#### Question

How to get the compiled schema in `build/data` with `./waf configure build` ?